# Magento two module overriding customer_group_edit_form, only one module works

Tags: block, admin

Let say I have module named module_one, in this module I'm overriding customer_group_edit_form in config.xml to add another fieldset in the customer group page of the admin. Everything works fine until I create another module named module_two which also override customer_group_edit_form in the customer group page, the problem is the fieldset of of module_two is not showing since it is being overlapped by module_one. When I try to comment out the customer_group_edit_form of module_one the customer_group_edit_form of module_two is showing.

Is there some way I can set fieldset order in overriding customer_group_edit_form?

Answer (score 0):

By couple of tracing and debugging I jump into one solution which I just override the module_one block so it will look somthing like this in Group.php

class Extensioname_Moduleone_Block_Adminhtml_Group
    extends Extensioname_Moduletwo_Block_Adminhtml_Group

If you have another solution, please let me know.